# File listener - how can I know when the file is accessable?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a file listener on a win service.

I raise event on file created/

some time I get execption "cannot access to the file because it being used by another program"
do someone has an idea?

Comment: Lots of ideas. Not sure what you are asking though.

Comment: Maybe creator of the file has an exclusive lock on the file. This would cause a kind of exception you are experiencing

Answer (score 1):

You could use `FileSystemWatcher` to get notification on the file system but you should be more explicit if possible.

More info on it here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, even when using a FileSystem watcher, is simply to do a Thread.Sleep(1000) after the FileCreated (or whichever event you are watching) has fired, so that you are 100% sure that the previous process has done with it. I have had a similar experience when using FileSystem watchers, and pausing for a while before trying the access the file fixed the issue.